# What does "Potochoterophii Fohsiensis" possibly mean in a Latin cryptogram from "Cocker's Decimal Arithmetic" textbook?

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation

I was reading an old math textbook, *Cocker's Decimal Arithmetic*, and came across this cryptogram:

[image]

The question I have is about the beginning of the text:

> *Anixo guo Anamfiggino* Jorammi Lehkeg *Lofoxrofeholrii Torgiemgig Im Xonifafu Disohemiemgi Puwinasigfeho.*

Since the vowels haven't been changed, it's easy to decipher this, using a simple substitution cipher:

> *Amico suo Amantissimo* Johanni Perkes *Potochoterophii Fohsiensis in Comitatu Wigoreniensi Ludimagistero.*

Which translates roughly to:

> *To his dearest friend* John Perkes *[Potochoterophii Fohsiensis] in County Worcestershire Schoolmaster.*

And this is where I got stuck. Can anyone help me figure out what "Potochoterophii Fohsiensis" might mean, or point me to resources to help me figure it out?

Comment: It would help if you could list the substitutions. Right now I fail to see how one is to deduce t -> f. Does f -> t imply t -> f? Generally "-iensis" indicates "of" in the sense of being from some place. E.g. floresiensis = of Flores (an island in Indonesia). So "Foh" would be the place name in this case, however I am not aware of any locality by that name in Worcestershire.

Comment: "Potochoterophii" has a Greek feel to it. "Ptochotrophii", perhaps. ptóchos: (of one who crouches and cowers, hence) beggarly, poor; trophé: nourishment, food. Correction to previous comments: Fohs-iensis -> "of Fohs". Which does not make any sense either.

Comment: @njuffa Sorry about that. I didn't list the substitutions because I didn't think they were germane: I was asking a question about Latin, not cryptography, and didn't want to clutter up my question. The substitutions are:

B=Z C=X D=W F=T G=S H=R L=P M=N N=M P=L R=H S=G T=F W=D X=C Z=B

You are correct that F=T implies T=F.

A,E,I,J,K,Q and Y are as written

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text is corrupt: the first word is meant to be ***Ptochotrophii***, as reflected in e.g. [this transcription](https://books.google.be/books?id=MbiHajVIbFAC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=Amico+suo+Amantissimo+Johanni+Perkes&source=bl&ots=gt-K-ht1Ii&sig=ACfU3U0D7eX-ABAVJ1HUK17arcIkqbHTZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_lK-d1LOBAxWngf0HHdYtB8QQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=Amico%20suo%20Amantissimo%20Johanni%20Perkes&f=false) from an encyclopedia from 1837. *Ptochotrophium* is a variant of *ptochotropheum*, which is a Latinisation of Greek πτωχοτροφεῖον 'poorhouse (lit. *beggar-feedery*)'.
The second word, too, is messed up: it should be *Fohliensis* (nom. *Fohliens*). This presumably identifies the specific poorhouse—Fohl's or Fohley's?—but a quick google does not yield a list of 17th-century poorhouses in Worcestershire, so that's where the search runs dry.

These aren't the only errors in the text: *Disohemiemgi/Wigoreniensi* should be *Disohmiemgi/Wigorniensi*, *Lèpeag* should be *lpeag*, *roughèg* should be *rouhg*, *feheafige* should be *fheafige*, *ruuz pe* should be *runzpe*, and John Hawkins' name at the end is actually given as John Hawki**m**s. These seem to be transmission errors, not Hawkins' own mistakes.

Comment: I found a [scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cocker_s_Decimal_Arithmetick_wherein_is/fmdnAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP19&printsec=frontcover) of an edition from 1685, and it has "Tor**p**iemgig" (or possibly even "T**e**r**p**iemgig"). Thus "Foh**l**iensis".

Comment: This older edition also has "Lòfoxrofèholrii"  and "Lèpeag", so perhaps accented letters were supposed to be omitted (so "Lèpeag" turns into "Pleas"), something that later typesetters overlooked. Also "roughèg" and  "fèheafige" (the accent on this last one is faint but does seem to be there).

Comment: @Cairnarvon I suspected the text was corrupted, because I had noticed the same spelling mistakes that you described in the decoded text, and I tend to agree that they are transmission errors. With your corrections, the text roughly translates to:  “_To his dearest friend_ John Perkes _of Foley’s Poorhouse in County Worcestershire Schoolmaster._” I believe “Foley’s Poorhouse” may be a reference to Oldwinsford Hospital, which is a school initially for poor children founded in 1667 by Thomas Foley, and which still exists to this day.